# How to automate adding different texts (names for examples) to one photo and export them as JPEG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, actions

I got a Certificate design as a PSD file. I have to add 1000 names to these Certificate!
I have the Excel file of the names. Is there anyway that we can automate it using Photoshop? Maybe using Action or Batch?!

Comment: See [the Data Driven graphics capabilities of Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html#:~:text=%20Create%20data-driven%20graphics%20%201%20Create%20the,your%20graphics%20by%20exporting%20them%20with...%20More%20)

Comment: Obligatory suggestion: You could also do this (data driven graphics / data merge) in **Illustrator** or even **Indesign**, both of which might be better for print and make your life easier but the benefit could also be negligible depending on things... Adobe documentation is pretty good, but to grasp the general idea youtube tutorials are probably better: [Illustrator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgeNiR1RJYc), [Photoshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W9C61U5jgU), [Indesign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1QV6R1y8Y0) (Skimmed through them without audio. Seemed to hit the main points)

Answer (score 2):

Make a mailmerge document that is essentially blank but position the name field so that *if the certificate image were placed there* the name would be aligned correctly. Make the merge, export to PDF.

Open the PDF and apply the PSD as a watermark "100%" "behind text". If PSD cannot be placed, "save as copy" the PSD to e.g. TIF